# Slow loading issues in edge and brave browsers and not Opera and Firefox

Tags: php, sql, browser, microsoft-edge, compatibility

I have been trying to fix extremely slow loading on my site until I have just tested it in another browser (opera) and it pings! No wait whatsoever. However in Edge and Brave it hangs for minutes... I am using php / xammp and the site is loading an sql resource (say, 50-100 results), then when iterating over it with simple markup like a <p>tag it just takes forever, or doesn't work at all. How can this be? Also I have  tested it in Firefox and it is lightning fast, just like on Opera

Edit: I understand that the iteration over an SQL resource happens server-side, and outputs before it is rendered in the browser, but that is what is puzzling me.

Comment: Edge and Brave are both based on chromium, I think first you can also test in Chrome. If it has the same issue in Chrome, then it might have something to do with chromium. Then you can open an issue on https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list. I tried to search similar issue on that site, but I don't find one. Besides, do you have any extensions installed in Edge and Brave? If you have, you can disable them and test again.

Comment: Thanks, Even though the problem was happening when using an sql resource, and would still break with simple <p> tags, I validated the page on w3 validator and fixed some minor errors until the page worked! I think the main issue was a conflict in the head with meta tags and the http-equiv attribute

Answer (score 1):

I validated the page on the w3 validator and having fixed a conflict with the meta tag       and the http-equiv attribute 'charset=utf-8', the page worked.